# Associations in Cakephp: BelongsTo is not working

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have a problem with associations in CakePHP.

I want that a Type has many Sections, so a Section belongs to Type

Models

```
   class Type extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Type';

        public $hasMany = array(
            'Section' => array(
                'className'     => 'Section',
                'foreignKey'    => 'type_id'
            )
        );
    }

class Section extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Section';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Type' => array(
            'className'    => 'Type',
            'foreignKey'   => 'type_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Controller

```
class SectionsController extends AppController {

    public function lista() {
            $this->set('sections', $this->Section->find('all'));
    }

}
```

But the result is this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Section' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'type_id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Advertising',
            'visible' => true
        )
    ),
```

Comment: The reason might be because you could not defined 'Type' in public `$uses` variable in the controller.

Comment: @ArunJain there should be no need to define `Type` in `$uses` if the association between models are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 $this->set('sections', $this->Section->find('all'));
```

(**NB:** without the `Type`)

This would include the `Type` fields in the form.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Section"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["Type"]=>
    array(0) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Your code will work if the relationship is `Section` `hasMany` `Type`